# Shooting 100 electrons at a wall

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises

I was wondering about something, this is actually a quantum mechanics homework. So if I shoot 100 electrons at a wall (in the same way after each other),(I'm gonna assume that there is no slit between the cannon and the wall).

So in order to sketch this, I would have to observe this experiment, so it won't act like a wave but rather as a particle. Would this mean that it won't have a probability density like it would have if a there was a slit between the electron cannon and the wall? When we observe this, we automatically lose any certainty of the momentum $\Delta p$, would this mean that the sketch would be some random dots against a wall?

Comment: The pattern of electron hits on the wall will always have a probability density describing how spread out or clustered they are. In this case the pattern is dictated by how the electron beam is generated - eg the aperture of the electron gun and the spread of velocities of the electrons which it emits.